# How to break long post title inside table td?

Tags: css, html-table

Today, I had the same issue when I wanted to render **long post titles** inside `table` `td` but all solutions here don't work as I wanted. So, after trying some tricks and tries I found the best solution for wrapping text as if it is a paragraph.

**The issue appears like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After digging online and trying some tips and tricks, I finally get it. I simply added a new div to wrap the entire `td` as follows: *(you can give that div a CSS class to avoid inline CSS warnings)*.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>
  <div style="white-space: break-spaces; width:300px;">Long Title Here</div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Now the final results will look like this:**

[image]

Thanks for your time :)

(Any Q&A are welcome).